# Finding Arc Lengths in a 3D cartesian coordinate system from any 2 arbitrary points

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, 3d, arc-length

So I'm familiar with the parametric form of the arc length integral that follows a given path at any point $t$, but what do you do when you have a 3D equation that does not follow any specific path $t$. For example say I have the equation:

$$f(x,y)=\exp[-(x^2+y^2)]+\exp[-((x-2)^2+(y-2)^2)]$$

and I want to find the path length of the curve from one maxima to the other? I've read that I need to use a "some numeric integration method" but I cannot find any more information than that online. The method used needs to be as accurate as possible, I have found the technique of using the Pythagorean theorem with approximation points on the path to be somewhat helpful, however it is lacking precision I'd prefer to use calculus. Thank you!

Edit:
Sorry, I should have clarified. Although you can simplify the above problem it was just an arbitrary example. I hope for a solution that can be utilized with any number of gaussian functions for example:

$$f(x,y)=\exp[-(x^2+y^2)]+\exp[-((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2)]+\exp[-((x-3)^2+(y-5)^2)]
$$
Thanks!

Comment: There's an infinite number of ways to go from $(0,0)$ to $(2,2)$. Which path do you want?

Comment: The most direct path as in only changing direction in z value, the x and y values should be a straight line, or in other words the path that would be a straight line if viewed from a birds eye view. Thanks!!

Comment: Also, since you say from one maxima to another, do you want these to be Gaussians instead?

Comment: If you're referring to using a Gaussian function that's okay but it doesn't need to be, I'm sure with your example I can rework it for Gaussian's. However if it's easier for you to do it with gaussians then by all means please do. Thanks!

Comment: No, the reason for my comment is that your function has two minima, not two maxima

Comment: Oh shoot I Just fixed it, thank you! Yes it should be gaussian then.

Answer (score 1):

First let's adjust the location of the maxima like so:

$$f(x,y) = \exp[-(x+1)^2-(y+1)^2] + \exp[-(x-1)^2-(y-1)^2]$$

as this does not change the path length. We can turn this into a $1$D problem by denoting

$$g(x) \equiv f(x,x) = \exp[-2(x+1)^2]+\exp[-2(x-1)^2]$$

where we now only have to find the path length of $g(x)$ on $[-1,1]$ (which is on the shortest path which connects the two maxima, $y=x$). The integral becomes

$$L = \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+ 16\left((x+1)\exp[-2(x+1)^2]+(x-1)\exp[-2(x-1)^2]\right)^2}\:dx$$

Since the function is even, we can reduce the domain of integration to $[0,1]$ at cost of a factor of $2$.

Now, according to Wolfram, we have that the max of the square of the derivative is $\approx 1.327$. Half of that is roughly $\frac{2}{3}$. Since on the interval $[0,1]$ we have that $$0 \leq [g'(x)]^2 < \frac{4}{3}$$ consider the following manipulation for a variable $x \in \left[0,\frac{4}{3}\right]$:

$$\sqrt{1+x} = \sqrt{\frac{5}{3}+\left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)} = \sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{3x-2}{5}\right)}$$

which has

$$-\frac{2}{5} \leq \frac{3x-2}{5} \leq \frac{2}{5}$$

which has a relatively small error for the Taylor approximation

$$\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{3x-2}{5}\right)} \approx \sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}\left(1+\left(\frac{3x-2}{10}\right)\right) = \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\left(\frac{4}{3}+\frac{1}{2}x\right)$$

which means that our arc length integral is approximately

$$L \approx \frac{8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} + 16\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\int_0^1 \left((x+1)\exp[-2(x+1)^2]+(x-1)\exp[-2(x-1)^2]\right)^2\:dx$$

After expanding and some substitutions, the integral portion above evaluates to

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{32}\operatorname{erf}(4) - \frac{7\sqrt{\pi}}{16e^4}\operatorname{erf}(2) - \frac{1}{4e^{16}} - \frac{1}{4e^8}$$

Plugging this is above, we get an analytic expression for the approximation of $L$ which is given numerically by

$$L \approx 2.5758$$

Compare this with the actual value of

$$L \sim 2.5491$$

Comment: Very thorough response thank you! But what do you do if the numbers don't work out so well so you cant do the x substitution for the y? Such as 3 or more exponent functions?

Comment: @PatrickWhite what do you mean?

Comment: As in a problem that cannot be reduced to 1 dimension, for example:
 exp[-(x^2+y^2)]+exp[-((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2)]+exp[-((x-3)^2+(y-5)^2)]

Sorry I should have lead with a problem like that, I didn't think anyone would come up with a clever 2d simplification :)

Comment: This is a very smart approximation, for sure. $\to +1$